# Creation of an object in a try block

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a homework assignment and have run into a problem that I cannot figure out the answer too in my book or online.  I'm not looking for someone to fix my code, I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

I am currently trying to create an object within a try block.  Prior to that try block I am asking the user to input 4 numbers.  These 4 numbers are the parameters for the object I am trying to create inside the try block.  I am unsure how to pass this data from the user into the try block.

My question is, how am I supposed to perform the creation of an object inside a try block?  I know my current code resets everything to 0 as soon as it hits the try block.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string choice;



        //Input once choice is made----------------------------------------------
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("**********************************************");

            Console.WriteLine("Create Checking Account \"C\"");
            Console.WriteLine("Create Checking Account \"S\"");
            Console.WriteLine("Quit the Application    \"Q\"");

            Console.WriteLine("**********************************************");

            Console.Write("Enter choice:  ");
            choice = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            if (choice != "Q")
            {

                switch (choice)
                {
                    case "C":


                        Console.Write("Enter a name for the Account:  ");
                        CA.setAccountName(Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()));
                        Console.Write("Enter an account Number:  ");
                        CA.setAccountNumber(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
                        Console.Write("Enter an initial balance:  ");
                        CA.setBalance(Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine()));
                        Console.Write("Enter the fee to be charged per transcation:  ");
                        CA.setFeeCharged(Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine()));
                        try
                        {
                            CheckingAccount CA = new CheckingAccount("",0,0,0);


                            CA.PrintAccount();
                        }

                        catch (Negative ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("**********************************************");
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }



                        break;
```

Comment: I am not clear on what your question actually is. It looks like you are already declaring an object inside your try block. What is the issue you are running into?

Comment: I needed to create the object prior to the try  block by setting it to null.  Then I never actually stored my users input.

Finally, once inside the try block with the code that is written, I would automatically reset everything to zero instead of using the user input data.

Answer (score 1):

What you can't do is reference an object before you even declare it. You have a lot of calls on reference `CA` before it is even declared and created below those calls.

About your question on the `try` block and creating an object: Create the pointer outside the `try` block and assign it inside the `try block. Then you have access to it outside the try block assuming there was no handled exception.

```
// outside of try
CheckingAccount CA = null;
try
{
     CA = new CheckingAccount("",0,0,0);
     /* Rest of the code unchanged*/
```

Comment: Thank you,  I had tried the CheckingAccount CA = Null; previously and couldn't figure out why that didn't work.  Between you and Crusha, I understand what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have a instance of an object called CA.
Before the try block you put datas in it, in the try block you a creating a new instance with the same name, this will overide your old instance and your datas are lost.
Why do you want a new instance in your try block?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Igor's answer:

Instead of directly setting the values that you just read, you need to store the values first, so that you can later pass them to the constructor of your object.

Instead of

```
CA.setAccountName(Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()));
```

use

```
// You probably don't even need the Convert.ToString() here,
// since the read line is already a string.
string accountName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
```

and later

```
// Do the same for the other values and replace the 0s.
CA = new CheckingAccount(accountName,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I knew I was doing something wrong that was really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Variables created outside a try block are still available inside it. So you can do this:

```
var accountName = Console.ReadLine();
var accountNumber = Int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
var balance = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
var feeCharged = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
try
{
    var CA = new CheckingAccount(accountName,accountNumber,balance,feeCharged);
    CA.PrintAccount();
}
catch
{
// stuff
}
```

If you need to use the account after the try block, declare it before. i.e. 
CheckingAccount CA = null;  somewhere before the try block.

Note: I would move handling the user input into the try block too. Users inputting something which cannot be converted to a number is an exception you probably want to handle.